# How to set AWS ALB ingress default action for non ssl and ssl ports

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using alb ingress controller and the ingress yaml file is pasted below.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: alb-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456789123:certificate/xxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-abce-ffffffffffff
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
         - path: /*
           backend:
             serviceName: ssl-redirect
             servicePort: use-annotation
    - host: domain.com
      http:
       paths:
       - backend:
          serviceName: greensvc
          servicePort: 80
         path: /green
       - backend:
          serviceName: redsvc
          servicePort: 80
         path: /red
    - host: mongo.domain.com
      http:
       paths:
       - backend:
          serviceName: mongo-express-service
          servicePort: 8081
```

corresponding rules in ALB is

[image]

[image]

ALB was deployed successfully but the logs from ingress "alb-ingress" reported two error

```
/*   ssl-redirect:use-annotation (<error: endpoints "ssl-redirect" not found>)

Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
```

what I am trying to achieve is to create a single default action (no need of any other rules) on port 80 which is forcing the https traffic. A default action in https port that is forwarded to a service, Along with other host or path based routing as per the scrren shot.  Currently both default action is set to return a fixed responce 404.

How can I modify current yaml file  such that the ALB rules will be updated as per my interest. Also why the ingress is logging the annotation error for ssl-redirect.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Using **apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1** worked for me.
You have to be aware of some changes needed to be done as you are using a different apiVersion as listed here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122

My final code was like these:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: ...
  name: ...
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.response-420: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"420","messageBody":"..."}}
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /myPath
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: response-420
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
```

Comment: Thankyou! this is what i was looking for, the "name" inside the port really helped me

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this myself, so please evaluate this closely before applying directly.

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: alb-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456789123:certificate/xxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-abce-ffffffffffff
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.response-404: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"404","messageBody":"Not Found"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.green-svc: >
      {"type":"forward","forwardConfig":{"targetGroups":[{"serviceName":"green-k8s-service","servicePort":80,"weight":100}]}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.green-svc: >
      [{"field":"host-header","hostHeaderConfig":{"values":["domain.com"]}},{"field":"path-pattern","pathPatternConfig":{"values":["/green"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.red-svc: >
      {"type":"forward","forwardConfig":{"targetGroups":[{"serviceName":"red-k8s-service","servicePort":80,"weight":100}]}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.red-svc: >
      [{"field":"host-header","hostHeaderConfig":{"values":["domain.com"]}},{"field":"path-pattern","pathPatternConfig":{"values":["/red"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.mongo-svc: >
      {"type":"forward","forwardConfig":{"targetGroups":[{"serviceName":"mongo-k8s-service","servicePort":8081,"weight":100}]}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.mongo-svc: >
      [{"field":"host-header","hostHeaderConfig":{"values":["mongo.domain.com"]}}]
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: response-404
    servicePort: use-annotation
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - backend:
              serviceName: green-svc
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - backend:
              serviceName: red-svc
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - backend:
              serviceName: mongo-svc
              servicePort: use-annotation
```

The default ALB rule is specified directly under the `spec` object but before the `rules` object.

For the annotations, actions and conditions are interpreted together when they share the same name.

The [Ingress Annotations](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/guide/ingress/annotations/) doc page for AWS LoadBalancer Controller has a lot of great examples that should be able to help you work out any other tweaks or changes you might want to make.  Specifically, check out [Traffic Routing](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/guide/ingress/annotations/#traffic-routing)